# $xy' + 1 = e^{x-y}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need help solving this differential equation

$xy' + 1 = e^{x-y}$

I wrote this as $xe^ydy = (e^x-e^y)dx$ and tried finding integrating factor but unsuccessfully. Any help will be much appreciated. I found this problem from entrance exam for some university

Comment: The equation is already exact as you have written it, hence there is no need to find an integrating factor.

Comment: it is not, left side is $-e^y$, the right side is $e^y$. am i wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiplying by $e^y$ gives $$xy'e^y+e^y=\frac{d}{dx}(xe^y)=e^x,$$so we get the general solution $$y=\ln\frac{e^x+C}x,$$ immediately.

Comment: Professor Vector, how this class of diff equations are called?

Comment: @MarkoffChainz: this is just a nonlinear ODE.

Comment: Daoust true but it's possible to rewrite a linear form of that ODE.

Answer (score 3):

From the way you have written your ODE, it is very likely that you were trying to solve your problem as an exact differential equation. Hence, I will continue using your approach.

---

As you have written it, there is **no need to find an integrating factor**. Recall that given functions $P (x,y) $ and $Q (x,y) $ with continuous partial derivatives in a certain domain $D $, the equation $P (x,y)~dx+Q (x,y)~dy=0$ is exact if and only if:
$$\frac {\partial P}{\partial y}=\frac {\partial Q}{\partial x} $$
Here, we have $P(x,y)=e^y-e^x $ and $Q (x,y)=xe^y $, and the condition satisfies.

Now just apply the standard procedure to solve such.

Comment: Thanks, now I see

Comment: Isnt  $P(x,y) = e^x-e^y$?

Comment: No. Rearrange your ODE to the form I mention. $$xe^y~dy=(e^x-e^y)~dx \implies (e^y-e^x)~dx+xe^y~dy=0$$

Comment: My bad. I wrote the  equation as $P(x,y)dx = Q(x,y)dy$ and forgot that I should move them to one side. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

$$e^{x-y}=\frac{e^x}{e^y}$$hence $$xy' + 1 = \frac{e^x}{e^y}\implies xy'e^y+e^y=e^x$$set $y=\ln u,e^y=u,y'=\frac {u'}u$ to get $$x\frac{u'}uu+u=e^x\implies xu'+u=e^x$$also note that $\dfrac{d}{dx}(xu)=xu'+u$ so we get $$\dfrac{d}{dx}(xu)=e^x\implies xu=\int e^x=e^x+c\implies u=\frac{e^x+c}{x}$$now remember that $y=\ln u$ to get $$\boxed {y=\ln\left(\frac{e^x+c}{x}\right)}$$

Answer (score 1):

***Hint***

Substitute $y=\ln(f(x))$ and $f(x)=e^y$

Then equation become simple...

I got

$$f'+\frac f x= \frac {e^x} x$$

$$xf'+ f =  {e^x}$$

$$(xf)' =  {e^x}$$

$$f=\frac {e^x+K} x$$

$$y =\ln(f)=\ln (\frac {e^x+K} x)$$

Answer (score 1):

We need to solve $$xy' + 1 = e^{x-y}$$ First multiply both sides by $e^{y}$ to get $$xy'e^{y} + e^{y} = e^{x}$$ Then notice that the left side is a total derivative
$$ (xe^{y})' = e^{x}$$ Integrate both sides to get $$ (xe^{y}) = e^{x} +C$$ Divide both sides by $x$ to get $$ e^{y} = (e^{x} +C)/x$$ Therefore $$ y = ln((e^{x} +C)/x).$$